# $q.all([somevar]).then(function(data)){}; , if somevar is 'undefined' when it will be resolved?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
$q.all([promise]).then(function(data)){
 console.log('resolved');
};
```

assume promise is 'undefined' when it will be resolved?
even promise is null or undefined , it is getting resolved,So confused about $q behavior.Please could you clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) can, even if not documented, take plain values as well and not only promises - it will automatically convert them. So your code is equivalent to

```
$q.all([$q.when(promise)]).then(function(data)) {
  console.log('resolved');
};
```

And if `promise` is `null`, you'll get a promise that is resolved with `null`, which is why you will finally see `[null]` in your `data`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.now clarified!!